# How to provide this code. Linq code i want simplify

Tags: c#, entity-framework, blazor

I have this code:

```
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id).Column1 = "a";
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id).Column2 = "b"; 
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id).Column3 = "c"; 
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id).Column4 = "d"; 
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id).Column5 = "e";
```

I want make something like this but i cannot

```
dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id){    
   Column1 = "a";    
   Column2 = "b";    
   Column3 = "c";      
   Column4 = "d";    
   Column5 = "e"; 
}
```

Comment: why not just store the result of `First` in a variable and set the properties on that variable? Something like `var element = dl.db.Table.First(x => x.id == T.id); element.Column1 = "a", ...`.

Comment: True, but my code have no solution ? @MakePeaceGreatAgain

Comment: what? What do you mean by "has no solution"?

Comment: Not more "correct" like this? @MakePeaceGreatAgain

`dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id){    
   Column1 = "a";    
   Column2 = "b";    
   Column3 = "c";      
   Column4 = "d";    
   Column5 = "e"; 
}`

Comment: because what you consider to be "correct", simply is not valid in C#. Object-initializer-syntax - as the name suggests - only works on object-initialization, which is directly after calling the appropriate constructor.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain not correct for me but for program...

Comment: If you did what you think is more correct (assign multiple row cells in a single statement) how could you know if one of them was wrong (for example a column type mismatch) which one of them is the problematic one?

Comment: You cannot simply state something that is invalid syntax to be the "correct" one, unless you create your own programming-language. This is simply not possible in C#, at least not the way you want it. The closest you get is within Mohammads answer.

Comment: @Cleptus before this block of code i guarantee i get the fields as i want actually this will never be problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First get the element from your table and store it into a varible, then modify that variable:

```
var e = dl.db.Table.First(x => x.Id == T.Id);
e.Column1 = "a";
e.Column2 = "b"; 
e.Column3 = "c"; 
e.Column4 = "d"; 
e.Column5 = "e";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you have is to use [`with`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/with-expression) expression. Some thing like this:

```
var p1 = new Person("Name1", 5);
var p2 = p1 with { Name = "Name2" };

record Person(string Name, int Age);
```

Comment: Yes, but only for `record` types, not for classes.

Comment: You've defined a `record` with which to use `with`.  How, if at all, can `with` be used to simplify the code in the question, though?